# Jquery Code Not Working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Happy Monday to all.

I am writing some very basic code to create a web page where my users can go, choose an item out of a drop down list, and then a file downloads base don your choice.

After some help I was able to get this working via jquery in the onchange event of the drop down box. I about did cartwheels when I got it to work in Firefox and then Chrome. I went to IE8 and bam!!! It doesn't work. This is pretty much par for the course.

This is my first experience with any type of javascript. I apologize for the seemingly simple question, but let me tell you it's driving me bananas!!

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.
js">   
 $(function() {
     $("#PrinterNames").change(function() {
         var printer = $(this).val();
         var url = "file:///C:/Users/JBenson/Desktop/PrinterScripts 

         /Completed"+"/"+ printer +".vbs";
     console.log(url);
         window.open(url,'Start Installation')
     });
});
</script>      
</head>

<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>

<img src=inspirelogo.gif>

<H2>Welcome to the HK Printer Installation Page!</H2>
      <H3>Please select a printer:
            <select id ="PrinterNames"  name ="PrinterNames" >
          <option value="Please Select a Printer" selected="selected">
 Please  Select a Printer</option>
          <option value="Acadia">Acadia</option>
                  <option value="Altima">Altima</option>
                  <option value="Armada">Armada</option>
                  <option value="Avalon">Avalon</option>
                  <option value="Blazer">Blazer</option>
                  <option value="Camaro">Camaro</option>
                  <option value="Caravan">Caravan</option>
                  <option value="Cavalier">Cavalier</option>
                  <option value="Celica">Celica</option>
                  <option value="Charger">Charger</option>
                  <option value="Chevelle">Chevelle</option>
                  <option value="Corolla">Corolla</option>
                  <option value="Corvair">Corvair</option>
                  <option value="Corvette">Corvette</option>
                  <option value="Daytona">Daytona</option>
                  <option value="Envoy">Envoy</option>
                  <option value="Escalade">Escalade</option>
                  <option value="Frontier">Frontier</option>
                  <option value="HHR">HHR</option>
                  <option value="Hummer">Hummer</option>      
                  <option value"Impala">Impala</option>
                  <option value="Insight">Insight</option>
                  <option value="Intrepid">Intrepid</option>
                  <option value="Journey">Journey</option>
                  <option value="Malibu">Malibu</option>
                  <option value="Maxima">Maxima</option>
                  <option value="Murano">Murano</option>
                  <option value="Neon">Neon</option>
                  <option value="Nomad">Nomad</option>
                  <option value="Nova">Nova</option>
                  <option value="Prowler">Prowler</option>
                  <option value="Sentra">Sentra</option>
                  <option value="Skyline">Skyline</option>
                  <option value="SSR">SSR</option>
                  <option value="Stratus">Stratus</option>
                  <option value="Versa">Versa</option>
                  <option value="Xterra">Xterra</option>

             </select> </H3>

<H3>Steps for Printer Installation </H3>
<ol>
      <li>Select your printer from the drop down above.</li>
      <li>You will get a pop up window that looks like this<br>
      <img src="printerinstall.jpg" alt="Download Box" ><br>
      Please click on open. It will iniate the installation.<br></li>
      <li>You may see a pop up box that looks like this during your installation<br>
      <img src="trustprinter.jpg" alt="Trust Printer"><br>
      Click on Install driver. <br></li>
      <li>After a few minutes, check your Devices and Printers and the printer you    

      selected should now be there.</li>
</ol>
<H3>Please contact the helpdesk at 6657 if you encounter any issues. </H3>

</body>
</html>
```

I am hoping this is something really simple that you need for IE. Any help you can provide would be so very appreciated. I am so tired of this issue I could throw the compy through a window.

Thanks again all!

Comment: Potentially stupid question: Do you actually *need* to support IE8?

Comment: Can you give us more information on how it doesn't work? Script error, wrong result, etc.?

Comment: Yeah we do actually have to support IE8. The outside vendors we deal with have sites and applications on their sites that work only in IE7 and IE8 so we have to keep it. I would change EVERYONE to firefox if I could.

Comment: Well Rup usually, on Firefox, when you choose and item from the drop down box, a box comes up for the download asking if you want to save, run, etc. In IE8, you select the item and nothing happens. I haven't run the debugging yet.

Comment: Just as a quick note as well, I'm doing this all through Notepad. My company wanted this and just kind of shoved it on my desk since I knew how to program C# and VB and the like. So unless I run it threw web tools, I have no debugging, just as a note.

Comment: IE8 has built-in developer tools. It's on the Tools menu, or F12. Do you have that `console.log` in your code in the normal case? That likely won't work in IE. You could use an `alert` instead temporarily. And do you really have that split url line in your code? I'd be surprised if that worked anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Rup. I'll give that developer tools a look. i took console.log out as well. I didn't split the line in the actual code :-) I just did that to fit it on the page here.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out:

```
console.log(url);
```

IE8 may spit up on `console`.

And, remember to include semicolons at the end of lines where they are appropriate. IE is not forgiving of JS errors like other browsers may be.

Run the code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or other JS debugger.

Here is a fiddle of your code to try: http://jsfiddle.net/WmS25/

Comment: In addition: Check this debug script. http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/ Instead of using console.log(url); you'd just use debug.log(url).  It gives you a ton of options, and works across all browsers.

Comment: jk. Ran the code through jslint. Again having no experience with javascript not sure if the errors I am getting are what is causing the issue or if it's just being picky about syntax? Could y'all take a look and tell me if these errors would cause this issue?

Comment: @JamiBenson I tested the `console.log` in IE8 on my own code and it did not run. Always use proper JS syntax as IE is particularly sensitive. Also, Chrome has JS debug tools built in. `Wrench` upper left, `Tools`, `Javascript console`.

Comment: @JamiBenson Added a fiddle to my answer. You can run the fiddle link in any browser you want to test. It has JSLint built in.

Comment: @JK Thanks so much for the fiddle. I had never seen that before. Cool stuff.  I ran it in evil IE8 and it says my JS code is valid. Only found one error I corrected. I hate to be such a pain, but do you have any other thoughts? Thanks again so much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JamiBenson Try changing the version of jquery you are using to 1.7 `<script script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">`